# Python 3 Dictionary "list indices need to be integers not str"

Tags: python-3.x

I have been doing anything I can think of, and it is now getting to the point where I have no clue where to go. After googling errors and general dictionary help I have ended up here...

I have not finished it, the bottom portion of main is not taken care of so disregard it. The preliminary testing has found this error and I do not like to build a program with the start not working as I am fairly new to Python. (this is also my first post on this forum, so if something is not up to snuff, please let me know)

```
def create(name, age):
    contact = {
        'name' : name,
        'age' : age,
        'email' : 'email',
        'phone' : 'phone',
        }



def getName(contact):
    name = input("What's their name? ")
    return contact[name]


def getAge(contact):
    age = int(input("What's their age? "))
    return contact ["name"]

def getPhone(contact):
    phone = input("What's their phone number? ")
    return contact['phone']

def getEmail(contact):
    email = input("What's their email? ")
    return contact['email']




def setName(contact, name):
    contact['name'] = name

def setAge(contact, age):
    contact['age'] = age

def setPhone(contact, phone):
    contact['phone'] = phone

def setEmail(contact, phone):
    contact['email'] = email

def birthday(contact):
    a = getAge(contact)
    a +=1
    setAge(contact, a)

def show(contact):
    print("Name: ", name)
    print("Phone number: ", phone)
    print("Age: ", age)
    print("Email: ", email)



def main():
    ann = create('Ann', 21)
    roland = create('Roland', 18)
    john = create ('John' , 19)
    print(getName("contact"))
    getAge()
    getPhone()
    getEmail()
    setName()
    setAge()
    setPhone()
    setEmail()
    show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you expect `getName("contact")` to do?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You are not returning created dict from `create()` function. Also, your calls in `main()` are not clear to me, basically nothing besides creating makes any sense. You have to pass created dicts as a arguments...

Comment: I am attempting to make a dictionary and access it with the functions listed. The majority of them (basically all of them not used yet in the main) are barebones and just meant to be an outline for now. I am just using the functions to make sure they work and tweak them. I understand that the bottom ones do need params, I simply have not gotten there yet.

Sorry if this is confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is return the contact `dict` from `create()`, like so:

```
def create(name, age):
    return {'name': name,
            'age': age,
            'email': None,
            'phone': None}
```

That way you'll have access to the `dict` that was created by the function call:

```
>>> john = create('John', 42)
>>> john
{'name': 'John', 'age': 42, 'email': None, 'phone': None}
>>> john['name'] == 'John'
True
>>> john['age'] == 42
True
```

Doing otherwise would result in a `TypeError`. You would see the same error when attempting to call any of your setter functions on the return value of your current implementation of `create()`. Take the following function:

```
def set_name(contact, name):
    contact['name'] = name
```

`set_name()` is expecting a `dict` which it will modify by changing the value of the `'name'` key to the value of `name`. This won't work if `contact` is `None`.

---

The error you are asking about is a result of your implementation of the following function:

```
def get_name(contact):
    name = input("What's their name? ")
    return contact[name]
```

If we walk through the body we will see the following, assuming we called it the way you did in your example code: (`get_name('contact')`)

```
>>> name == '<user input>'
True
>>> contact == 'contact'
True
```

So, when the function tried to read they key `name` from `contact` it was *actually* trying to read the character index of the string `"contact"` which only takes integers as indices. The function should probably read something like:

```
def get_name(contact):
    return contact['name']
```

Which would allow you to do the following: (using the same `john` as above)

```
>>> get_name(john)
'John'
```